# Angular7 service - returning observable that contains the data from another observable but subscribing to that second Observable within component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, angular-observable

I have a function in my service that returns an Observable (http request) that needs to be berformed with a special token. So - before being able to get this function, I need to have the token retreived to be able to make the request.

I've been looking at ways to chain these requests or retreiving that token to make sure its there before that request is being made, but because it is done in the constructor, when you load the page the very first time the token is not there and the HTTP request fails.

I currently have an if block in place in my service like this:

```
 if (!this.activeDirectoryToken) {
      this.adalService
        .acquireToken('https://graph.windows.net')
        .subscribe(token => {
          this.activeDirectoryToken = token;
// RETURN OBS LOGIC OF THE SECOND HTTP REQUEST USING THE TOKEN
            });
        } else {
// RETURN OBS LOGIC OF THE SECOND HTTP REQUEST USING THE TOKEN
```

But, of course, if I try subscribing to that function and the if block triggers, it will throw an error as 'subscribe' will not exist on that type.

I am also storing the token in the redux store and subscribing to it in the constructor of the service and I have another if block there to make a request for it in case it's null/false.

Nonetheless, that first request still fails due to not having the token set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method returns the token. If it was already cached then just return the current token else acquire a new token and cache it.

After that you can use `switchMap` to do the http request for your second part and subscribe.

```
getToken(): Observable<string> {
   if (this.activeDirectoryToken) 
       return Observable.of(this.activeDirectoryToken);

   return this.adalService
      .acquireToken('https://graph.windows.net')
      .pipe(
          do(token => this.activeDirectoryToken = token)
       );
}

secondPart(){
    this.getToken().pipe(
      switchMap( token => SECOND HTTP REQUEST USING THE TOKEN)
    )
    .subscribe(...);
}
```

Note: not tested